# Framerate limit for WPF apps?

Tags: wpf, performance, frame-rate

I wonder if there is a way to limit the WPF framerate within a process?
i.e. I do not want to limit a single animation's framerate, but the global
framerate for my whole application.

I think I've seen something like this before but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> ## How to control the frame rate for WPF animations
>
> Animations are very cool, but they can cause a high CPU load. One
> reason could be a missing hardware acceleration due to a old graphics
> adapter or a software rendering constraint. Another reason could be
> the the high frame rate of animations that is set to 60 fps by
> default.
>
> You can easily lower the framerate for all animations by overriding
> the DesiredFrameRate property of the timeline. Just add the following
> code to your project and play around with the setting to find a good
> tradeoff between performance and aesthetic.
>
> ```xml
> Timeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Timeline),  
> new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { DefaultValue = 30 });
> ```
>
> Or you can set the framerate individually for each animation in XAML, using the following code:
>
> ```xml
> Duration="0:0:0.5" 
>                  From="1.0" To="0.5" Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="30" />
> ```

## Source

https://www.wpftutorial.net/FrameRate.html